# My recursive fibonacci sequence isn't working correctly

Tags: c++

Here is my code.When I type 5, it returns 5. I don't know where am going wrong.
I will be glad if you pointed where am going wrong.thanks.

```
#include <iostream>


int fSeq(int n)


{
 if (n==0)
{
 return 0;
}
else if(n==1)
{
return 1;
}

else
{

    return fSeq(n-1)+fSeq(n-2);
}

}
int main() 
{

int s;
std::cout<<"Please enter a number"<<'\n';
std::cin>>s;
// insert code here...

std::cout << fSeq(s)<<'\n' ;
return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I believe Fib(5) is actually 5.
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fibonacci_number

Answer (score 0):

Wrong points of your code are:

- bad formatting
- the meaningless comment `// insert code here...`
- absence of error checking for invalid input and overflow in the arithmetic

The Fibonacci sequence looks like `0, 1, 1, 2, 3, 5, 8, 13, ...` and the 5th term is `5`.

**UPDATE:** An example of corrected code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <climits>

int fSeq(int n)
{
    if (n < 0)
    {
        std::cout << "invalid input" << '\n';
        exit(1);
    }
    else if (n == 0)
    {
        return 0;
    }
    else if(n == 1)
    {
        return 1;
    }
    else{
        int ret1 = fSeq(n - 1);
        int ret2 = fSeq(n - 2);
        if (ret1 > INT_MAX - ret2)
        {
            std::cout << "overflow detected" << '\n';
            exit(1);
        }
        return ret1 + ret2;
    }
}

int main(void) {

    int s;
    std::cout << "Please enter a number" << '\n';
    if (!(std::cin>>s))
    {
        std::cout << "read failed" << '\n';
        return 1;
    }

    std::cout << fSeq(s) << '\n';
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Thank you for the feedback.                                                                    >absence of error checking for invalid input and overflow in the arithmetic     How do I check for that?   How is the right format? Thanks.